# How to pass a SQL call into an AWK script to dictate text replacement on a file?

Tags: bash, sqlite, awk, gsub

I am working on a script to do some personal accounting and budgeting. I'm sure there are easier way to do this, but I love UNIX-like CLI applications, so this is how I've chosen to go about it.

Currently, the pipeline starts with an AWK script that converts my CSV-formatted credit card statement into the plain-text into the double-entry accounting format that the [CLI account program Ledger can read](https://www.ledger-cli.org/). I can then do whatever reporting I want via Ledger.

Here is my AWK script in its current state:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F "," 'NR > 1 {
    gsub("[0-9]*\.[0-9]$", "&0", $7)
    gsub(",,", ",", $0)
    print substr($2,7,4) "-" substr($2,1,2) "-" substr($2,4,2) " * " $5
    print "  Expenses:"$6" -"$7
    print "  Liabilities  "$7"\n"
}' /path/to/my/file.txt
```

Here is a simulated example of the original file (data is made up, format is correct):

```
POSTED,08/22/2018,08/23/2018,1234,RALPH'S COFFEE SHOP,Dining,4.33,
POSTED,08/22/2018,08/24/2018,1234,THE STUFF STORE,Merchandise,4.71,
POSTED,08/22/2018,08/22/2018,1234,PAST DUE FEE,Fee,25.0,
POSTED,08/21/2018,08/22/2018,5678,RALPH'S PAGODA,Dining,35.0,
POSTED,08/21/2018,08/23/2018,5678,GASLAND,Gas/Automotive,42.38,
POSTED,08/20/2018,08/21/2018,1234,CLASSY WALLMART,Grocery,34.67,
```

Here are the same entries after being converted to the Ledger format with the AWK script:

```
2018-08-22 * RALPH'S COFFEE SHOP
  Expenses:Dining -4.33
  Liabilities  4.33

2018-08-22 * THE STUFF STORE
  Expenses:Merchandise -4.71
  Liabilities  4.71

2018-08-22 * PAST DUE FEE
  Expenses:Fee -25.00
  Liabilities  25.00

2018-08-21 * RALPH'S PAGODA
  Expenses:Dining -35.00
  Liabilities  35.00

2018-08-21 * GASLAND
  Expenses:Gas/Automotive -42.38
  Liabilities  42.38

2018-08-20 * CLASSY WALMART
  Expenses:Grocery -34.67
  Liabilities  34.67
```

Ledger can do all sorts of cool reporting on the different categories of spending and earning. My credit card automatically assigns assigns categories to things (e.g. Expenses:Gas/Automotive, Expenses:Dining, etc.), but they are not always categoried in a way that reflects what was spent. I also want to be able to put in sub categories, such as Expenses:Dining:Coffee.

To do this, I created a SQLite database that contains the mappings I want. A query like:

```
SELECT v.name, tlc.name, sc.name 
FROM vender AS v 
JOIN top_level_category AS tlc ON v.top_level_category_id = tlc.id
JOIN sub_category AS sc ON v.sub_category_id = sc.id;
```

will output data like this:

```
RALPH'S COFFEE SHOP, Dining, Coffee
```

I want to figure out a way to pass the above SQL query into my AWK script in such a way that when AWK finds a vendor name in a line, it will replace the category assigned by the credit card with the category and subcategory from my database.

Any advice or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Ed Morton I did, it's towards the bottom of the post. I updated the languate to make it more explicit that the offered SQL query is the query I want AWK to invoke.

Comment: @Ed Morton Yes, the database is read-only by AWK. Its there to hold the text-replacement permutations so that my script isn't cluttered by hundreds of conditional gsub() statements.

Comment: To the extent there is a 'normally', I'd expect to use a program designed to talk to the database to collect or modify the data, leaving Awk or other tools to do the presentation work (converting the data returned by the program into a more readable format).  For the formatting, Awk is good.  The program used might have a name like `isql`, `dbaccess`, `sqlcmd`, `pgsql`, `mysql` or …